# Partition algorithm runtime error. Can someone help me to find what is wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, partition

I have written an array partition algorithm in C, but it gives me the error "segmentation fault: core dumped".
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int n;
printf("insert array width\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
--n;
int A[n];
int i,j,p;
int x,t;

//inserimento valori array
printf("insert values\n");
for (i=0; i<=n; ++i){
scanf("%d", &A[i]);
}

printf("the array A is:\n");
for (i=0; i<=n; ++i){
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

This is the actual partition algorithm, and for sure the problem is here.

```
printf("insert the pivot value\n");
scanf("%d", &x);
i=0;
j=n;
while (i<j && A[i]<=x){
    ++i;
    }
while (i<j && A[j]>x){
    ++j;
    }
if (A[j]>x) {
    --j;
    }
while (i<j){
    t=A[i];
    A[i]=A[j];
    A[j]=t;
    ++i;
    ++j;
    while (A[i]<=x){
        ++i;
        }
    while (A[j]>x){
        ++j;
        }
    }
p=j;

printf("the result of the operation is:\n");
for (i=0; i<=n; ++i){
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me to find what is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: First mistake I see, you assume that `scanf()` was successful.'

Comment: Array index range from `0` to `n-1`. So `for (i=0; i<=n; ++i)` should be `for (i=0; i<n; ++i)` and similar changes in other loops. And why do you do `--n` after reading `n`?

Comment: If the pivot value is out of range of the data, indexing will break the array bounds.

Comment: In `while (i<j && A[j]>x){ ++j; }` you increment `j` but `j` was initialised to `n`. So `j` should be decremented.

Comment: I did --n; because the code is pasted from another program where I asked how many values there would be in the array. In c the first element index is 0, so without --n; putting 9 would mean an array with 10 values. This is not what causes the program to crash.

Comment: In future, don't confuse the number of elements with the index. If there are `n` elements you index `0 <= index < n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--n;
int A[n];
```

Now `A` has `n-1` elements, but you still access element n, which doesn't exists. At least swap the two lines, or keep the original n value since it's more C-ish (and run the loops until `i<n`).

```
while (i<j && A[j]>x){
    ++j;
    }
```

You should decrease `j`.
In the rest of the code you keep incrementing j, but I'm fairly sure you should decrement it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I don't know how I didn't see such an obvious error given that I spent hours trying to find what the heck was wrong with it.